# python virtual env somehow using wrong pip

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

strugging to get `pip install` working with virtualenv.

```
$ virtualenv env
$ source env/Scripts/activate
```

I now have two python installations:

```
(env) $ where python
D:\my_folder\env\Scripts\python.exe
C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3\python.exe
```

I am using the one I want:

```
(env) $ which python
D:\my_folder\env\Scripts\python.exe
```

Same with pip:

```
(env) $ where pip
D:\my_folder\env\Scripts\pip.exe
C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip.exe

(env) $ which pip
D:\my_folder\env\Scripts\pip.exe
```

However I have the following

```
(env) $ pip -V
pip 18.0 from C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.6)
```

wrong place!

```
(env) $ pip freeze
... dumps out my global packages!!

(env) $ pip install requirements.txt
... fails because requirements cannot be met.
```

I have a feeling that I have bad environment variable somewhere but don't really know where to look?! I'm just coming over from node and npm and finding python modules to be a bit of a car crash (although the language is awesome). Anyhow all help appreciated.

(EDIT)

OK, so (thanks to @alec_djinn) the following works:

```
python -m pip install requirements.txt
```

however

```
python -m pip freeze
```

still dumps my global installations.

Comment: would it be a good solution to specify the interpreter directly? `D:\my_folder\env\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Ah - ok that worked. So is the solution never to call `pip <args>` but rather `python -m pip <args>`. That kind of makes sense (if a tad verbose) - thank you

Comment: does not work for `python -m pip freeze` however. My head hurts

Comment: because `python` is probably not linked to the interpreter you expect, that is why it is a very good idea to specify the full path to the interpreter so that you are sure which python installation you are going to use for that env.

Comment: @alec_djinn. So if I am understanding correctly `which python` does not tell you what python you are linked to? What does linking mean in this context and what does `which python` actually tell me? Thanks.

Comment: Just to follow up using the full path still does not work with `pip freeze`!

Comment: have you tried `D:\my_folder\env\Scripts\python.exe -m pip freeze` ? It works in my case (with my specific path of course).