# pip version conflicts , how to know the right pip version

Tags: python, pip

I have very strange behavior about pip version

when we run `pip --version` , we get:

```
[root@dev_linux01 python_files]# pip --version
pip 8.1.2 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

but when we run `pip freeze` in order to find some match modules , then pip say that we have `pip version 18.0`

```
[root@dev_linux01 python_files]#  pip freeze | grep sys
You are using pip version 18.0, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

what is happens here ? 
how to verify the real pip version?

```
pip2 --version
pip 8.1.2 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

[root@dev_linux01 python_files]# pip3 --version
bash: pip3: command not found...
Similar command is: 'pip'

[root@dev_linux01 python_files]# pip --version

pip 8.1.2 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

Comment: do you perhaps have multiple python versions installed? e.g. `pip2 --version` vs `pip3 --version`

Comment: see please the update question

Comment: I see, so you have no `python 3`. That means my initial guess was wrong. I'm simply guessing, but do the outputs of `which pip`, `where pip` and `whereis pip` look like you'd expect?

Comment: which pip
/usr/bin/pip

Comment: also see [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4754). e.g. `sudo -H pip --version`?

Comment: sudo -H pip --version
pip 8.1.2 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204266/discussion-between-judy-and-lucidbrot).

Comment: [Related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52605630/2550406) points out that `pip freeze` behaves differently from `pip install`